# Can WiFi cause health problems?

Tags: electromagnetism, wifi

The following letter was delivered to every house in our village. It contains many claims about the health risks of WiFi, mobile phones and microwaves.

It also claims several countries have band the use of WiFi in schools.

Does anyone have sources for any of the claims made in this letter?

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]
[image: Page 4]

Comment: The question is currently very broad and a duplicate, but if you wanted to extract an individual claim from the long list of claims, we could tackle that.